# Is the Nyaboron ending song a real one, or just made for concept?

Tags: the-pet-girl-of-sakurasou

I was watching "Sakurasou no Pet na Kanojo" again. In episode 12, when the game "Nyaboron" ended, it plays a song. Is that song available anywhere, or just made for concept of anime?

## SSs

**Ep12 @ 13:32**
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was purpose-composed for the anime, so it's not "real", per se. Nonetheless, you can find the full version of it (4:00 in length), titled "Utsukushiki Ai no Hoshi yo, Eien ni" as track #5 on [the anime's second soundtrack](http://vgmdb.net/album/35765). 13:32 into the episode corresponds to about 0:15 into the song.

Here's a Youtube link (which could go down at any time): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycmL6Mrpo30#t=13m25s.